# github action maven dependency caching

Tags: java, maven, github, github-actions

I introduce myself currently into github actions and several maven operations.
I think I have some missunderstanding how the dependency caching is working inside my github actions.
I have this action:

```
runs:
  using: composite
  steps:

    - name: Cache m2 dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: .m2/repository
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
    - name: Run ${{ inputs.name }}
      run: mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Order" -Dexec.args="${{ inputs.order }}" -B
      shell: bash
```

This action is executed without problem 5 times within my pipeline chane.

But... In each task the dependencies are downloaded again. In my case 5 times.
I thought I get rid of that with the "Cache m2 dependencies" ?
The cache is recognized:

```
Received 46137344 of 81878765 (56.3%), 10.9 MBs/sec
73
Received 71303168 of 81878765 (87.1%), 13.5 MBs/sec
74
Received 81878765 of 81878765 (100.0%), 13.5 MBs/sec
75
Cache Size: ~78 MB (81878765 B)
76
/bin/tar -z -xf /__w/_temp/883f2a2b-30d5-4597-bd4e-230d73e83443/cache.tgz -P -C /__w/test-prj/test-prj
77
Cache restored successfully
```

however in the next step "Run ${{ inputs.name }}" everything is downloaded again and again.

```
[INFO] ----------------< test-prj >----------------
199
[INFO] Building test-prj 1.0
200
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
201
[INFO] Downloading from thirdparty-rep: https://thirdparty-rep.com/public/repositories/maven/io/appium/java-client/7.4.1/java-client-7.4.1.pom
202
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/appium/java-client/7.4.1/java-client-7.4.1.pom
203
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/appium/java-client/7.4.1/java-client-7.4.1.pom (4.7 kB at 55 kB/s)
204
[INFO] Downloading from thirdparty-rep: https://thirdparty-rep.com/public/repositories/maven/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.pom
205
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.pom
```

Besides of my dependencies in the pom.xml, I have additionaly placed a repository for some third-party libs:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-third-party-repo</id>
        <url>https://thirdparty-rep.com/public/repositories/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

maybe you see my problem with the caching...

Comment: Did you try adding `uses: actions/cache@v2...` to the other task too?

Comment: It is always the same task but with different input

Comment: Can you show the exact key that is used to restore cache ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski  Linux-maven-c1aeb95006c18983cede8838a04297a07d42d08b1204053f2e1a2bf076b9954a
and the key is the same for all the actions within the pipeline.

Comment: Try `path: ~/.m2/repository` instead of `path: .m2/repository`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

1. You changed the POM file in between. Then the cache is deleted.
2. Maven is often downloading external POMs to evaluate dependency graphs. I do not really know why, but as long as no JAR files are downloaded, I would not worry to much because POMs are really small and downloaded super fast.

Comment: ahhh the file extension is always pom... Even in my case. so it is just downloaded by maven to take care of the depencies? and if yes... is there an option flag to disable it?

Comment: and there are also jars downloaded

Comment: If the JARs are SNAPSHOT versions, then they are usually redownloaded every day. The update policy can be configured in the `settings.xml`.